# Would it be possible to write a SSO Web Service on a DNN 5 site?

Tags: dotnetnuke, single-sign-on

A client has 2 older DNN 5 sites and they're looking to have a new DNN site built. They want to stay with DNN 5 because of a Single-Sign On feature they had developed a while back. We're recommending DNN 7 for obvious reasons.

We'd like to build a web service that could be called from the DNN7 site that would sign them in to their other DNN 5 sites. Could something like this be integrated with DNN 5?

Comment: Wow, a down-vote for a completely legit question...thanks :s We're still at the "spec" stage so I'm curious if the DNN architecture would allow us to write a Web Service or even a page that we could call remotely with credentials log in the user so that when the navigate to one of their DNN 5 sites they'd automatically be logged in. Not sure why that question deserved a down-vote.

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to do advertising, but the company that I work for, Interzoic, has a product like the one you described, so yes, it is possible. Here is the link to the product page: http://www.interzoic.com/single-sign-on

Comment: Haha, it's .NET so I don't expect to get much for free :p Just working on getting a detailed description from the client about how their current SSO solution works. Once I get that, I'll contact you guys, thanks!